# TypeError at /posts/12/tesing/like/ quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Well i am trying to add like toggle or like button in my project and got this error . How can i fix this error ?

view.py

```
class PostLikeToggle(RedirectView):
    
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')
        print(slug,'slug')
        pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')
        print(pk,'pk')
        obj =get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk,slug=slug)
        print(obj,'post')
      
        user=self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                obj.likes.remove(user)
            else:
                obj.likes.add(user)
        return redirect(f'/posts/{pk}/{slug}')
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 193, in get
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 485, in __init__
    self['Location'] = iri_to_uri(redirect_to)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 147, in iri_to_uri
    return quote(iri, safe="/#%[]=:;$&()+,!?*@'~")
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 839, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "C:\Users\AHMED\anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 864, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")

Exception Type: TypeError at /posts/12/tesing/like/
Exception Value: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

if more detail is require than tell me i will update my question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_redirect_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.get_redirect_url) should return a string, not an `HttpResponse`

Change it to:

```
return f'/posts/{pk}/{slug}'
```